# Trying to loop one column from data frame and trying to get the sentiment analysis for all the rows in the column. I'm unable to get that

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

**I'm trying to loop one column from data frame and trying to get the sentiment analysis for all the rows in the column. I'm unable to get that.**

The code is below

```
df.head()
```

Output is

```
    sentence
0   Hey, hello
1   How are you? 
2   this is too bad.
3   Where are you?
4   Time is up, come soon
```

The code for sentiment analysis is

```
word = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    word.append(str(row[0]))
```

In the above code I'm appending all the rows to the list.

```
review_text = word

encoded_review = tokenizer.encode_plus(
  review_text,
  max_length=MAX_LEN,
  add_special_tokens=True,
  return_token_type_ids=False,
  pad_to_max_length=True,
  return_attention_mask=True,
  return_tensors='pt',
```

Followed by code below

```
input_ids = encoded_review['input_ids'].to(device)
attention_mask = encoded_review['attention_mask'].to(device)
output = model(input_ids, attention_mask)
_, prediction = torch.max(output, dim=1)
print(f'Review text: {review_text}')
print(f'Sentiment  : {class_names[prediction]}')
)
```

Output is in the below format

```
Review text: ['Hey, hello', 'How are you?']
Sentiment: Positive
```

**In the above output for example if there are 10 rows, I'm getting only one sentiment for all the rows.**

Comment: try writing a function to calculate sentiment, then use `df['sentence'].apply(my_function)`

Comment: Can't we loop the class_names[prediction]?

Comment: Sure, but that's a slower way of doing the apply

Comment: Can you write code, please?

Comment: There are plenty of examples on here of how to do it, I can't write the code for you.

Comment: Okay will look into it